# Redirect sysout to some other file in tomcat8

Tags: tomcat, stdout, tomcat8

How to redirect System.out messages to some other file in tomcat8? 
Currently they are logging into tomcat8-stdout.log file.

I have tried following things till yet: 1) added RollingFileAppenders in log4j files to redirect sysout to some other file. but its not working. 2) Tried by removing java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler. from logging.properties. still no luck

Comment: Answer should be here somewhere: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Console

Comment: @Neel, show some effort you did try to solve it yourself by letting us know what you tried sofar as a starter.

Comment: @ZF007. I have tried following things till yet: 
1) added RollingFileAppenders in log4j files to redirect sysout to some other file. but its not working.
2) Tried by removing java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler. from logging.properties. still no luck.

Comment: Please post that information from comment into your question. Comments can easily be deleted.. questions not. And respond to jdv's comment as well  by either improving your question or comment... as long as the latter one is not lots of code (should be in question or self-posted answer). Finally, finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)